# query data from two tables using mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select patient_id from patient where date(visit.date_started) > date(patient.date_created)
```

The statement i think is self explanatory to what i am trying to do. I have two tables, **patient** and **visit**. I want to get patients who have started a visit, which is recorded on another table, on a later day than when the patient was registered in the system, which a patient is recorded when registered.
note: All i need returned is the data on the patients table after the filter.

Comment: Please refer to this link for some hints about how to build your query: [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Comment: what is the relation between "patient" and "visit" tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select patient.id
from patient,visit 
where date(visit.date_started) > date (patient.date_created)
```

Comment: Thank you. this solution works well but it combines both tables into one table than returning only data from the first table

Comment: it return only what you select, in this case you select "patient.id"